# Admin is not saving the conguration changes magento 1.9

Tags: session, caching, configuration, admin, magento-1.9

When I make some changes in admin , after saving the configuration , the changes are not reflection on admin but when I logout from admin and again get log into the admin the changes reflects on admin panel ?

I have renamed the var folder but nothing is happen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbWL7.png)

e.g. 'call to order' is set to no , and if I change it to yes and save it then it will not refelect the changes. But if I log out from the panel  and do login again it will show the changes I made before.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please provide some code, commands or error message to your issue? Please also have a look to the Help Center regarding [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: There is no error in error log . I do not understand if this issue is related to session because the changes are reflecting when you again log into the admin panel.

Comment: you may want to share more details about your magento instance. something like a list of custom modules, session configuration etc.

Comment: The problem was with session file .. I have changed   <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save> to   <session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save> .. Now admin is working fine..

Comment: Now the problem is that How will I handle my database. Should I run the cron to clean the session from database for every 5 days.??

Comment: Again ran into the same issue .. Any help..??